# How would I type a character in readline-sync to do a specific task? (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a list in readline-sync and in order to complete a task you need to type an option (for example "1" or "2"). I want to make it so that when you type "1" it goes to supremenewyork.com, and when you type "2", it makes you go to google.com. Here is my code:

```
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync'),
  commands = ['Supreme', 'Google'],
  index = readlineSync.keyInSelect(commands, 'What would you like to do today?');
  const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require("selenium-webdriver");
  async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    await driver.get("https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all");
  }
  example();
;

const {Builder, By, Key, util} = require("selenium-webdriver");
  async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    await driver.get("https://google.com");
  }
  example();
;
```

How would I make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This works**

This uses the termninal child_process to start chrome, but you can use whatever you like.

For readline (async)

```
const readline = require('readline');
const {exec} = require("child_process")

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

function cmdCommand(cmd){
    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        
        console.log(`Progress: ${stdout}`);    
    });
}

rl.question('1 or 2 ', (answer) => {
 
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);
  answer === "1"? cmdCommand("start chrome supremenewyork.com"):""
  answer === "2"? cmdCommand("start chrome google.com"):""

  rl.close();
});
```

For readline-sync

```
const readline = require('readline-sync');
const {exec} = require("child_process")


function cmdCommand(cmd){
    exec(cmd, (error, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(`error: ${error.message}`);
            return;
        }
        
        console.log(`Progress: ${stdout}`);    
    });
}

const reader = require("readline-sync"); 
let answer = reader.question("1 or 2");

answer === "1"? cmdCommand("start chrome supremenewyork.com"):""
answer === "2"? cmdCommand("start chrome google.com"):""
```